# jQuery draggable / droppable problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I can drag items without any problem unfortunately items can be dragged everywhere which I do not want. I only want items to be dragged on some specific areas such as buttonmenu. I used many methods but I have not got any result. Could you please tell me how to disable a buttonmenu which has id of 34 not to drop buttons there? You can see the code that I am using (which does not work for not droppping)

Best Regards

Altaico

Here is the code:

```
$("#35").draggable();
$("myArticle").droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the revert: invalid option on the draggable object which will caused it to snap back if it is dropped onto anything not marked as droppable, so try:

```
$("#35").draggable({revert: "invalid"}));
$("myArticle").droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
$("#36").droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
```

This means you'd be able to drag 35 onto 36 but not onto myarticle.

Below is the full page html:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
      $("#35").draggable({revert: "invalid"});
      $("#36").droppable({disabled: false });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="34" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"> 
    </div>
  <div id="35" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow;" >
     </div>
  <div id="36" style="width:300px; height:300px; border:solid blue 1px;">
    drop me here
  </div>
</body>
```

This renders 2 coloured blocks (the divs). You can drag the yellow one (id 35) and drop it only in the square labelled "drop me here". If you wanted to drop it anywhere else, you'd have to decorate that area with droppable

Hope this helps

Comment: JonNeale

I am not able to drop my button after I use your code. I am able to drag it but I cannot drop it anywhere. I will be glad if you can help me about that...I am looking for your helps. cheers.

Comment: I fixed a bug in the html demo listed above which would cause the div to be draggable but not droppable. Basically there needed to be something in the div. Can you confirm that the demo html, does what you want it to do? Playing with the demo, I can pick up div 35 and drop it only in div 36

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `accept` option for your droppable element - this allows you to either specify which classes the dragged element must have before it will be consider for a drop oeration, or a function which you can use to make this decision based on some other criteria.

Comment: I can only drag my buttons but I am not able to drop it anywhere after I use that code. I will be so glad if you can help me about that issue. Cheers. Altaico
 
[code]
$().ready(function() {
     $("#technologyBtn").draggable({revert: "invalid"});
$("#myArticle").droppable( "option", "disabled",false );
$("#techBtnMenu").droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
 alert("end");
    });

[/code]

Comment: When you say you can't drop it, what behaviour are you expecting to see when your let go of the mouse button?